# The standard way for switching from/to user_timezone and gmt

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, timestamp

I use php's `date_default_timezone_set()` and set it according to user's `timezone` field in the the user table. So with ease I can show date/time to users and get date/time from them.

But for storing date related values in database, I have to use the standard GMT timezone.

The question: **What is the *best* or maybe the *standard* way for switching to/from user_timezone and GMT?**

Do you suggest me to follow these steps when I want to insert or update a field in database?

1. Change the timezone using `date_default_timezone_set('GMT');`
2. Get the time using `$inserttimestap = time();` or `$inserttimestamp
   = mktime();`
3. Change the timezone back to user default using: `date_default_timezone_set($this->session->userdata('timezone'));`

Comment: I would say the best way is to not misue the default time-zone setting by wasting it for the user but instead making the application aware how to display a date or time to the user.

Comment: As I've researched, setting the `date_default_timezone_set()` according to user does not look to be a **misuse**. If I don't do that, I would have a lot of troubles dealing with user_timezone for both reading and showing date/time. Further, the application that I write doesn't use Gregorian calendar. It should use Persian (Jalali) date. So my problems will increase if I don't want to set the default timezone according to user timezone.

Comment: Might be, I only called it misuse. You can turn my statement 180 and then it only means that when you store the times, you need to have the application timezone (which is fixed, e.g. GMT). That's all. So when you store convert the date to a GMT timestamp and when you read, convert it back to a user timestamp. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to use `date_default_timezone_set('GMT')` because for converting to GMT, there is a special set of functions that the function names begin with 'gm':

- `gmmktime()` gets a timestamp in GMT timezone.
- `gmdate()` that gives a GMT date format.
- There is also `gmstrftime()` [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmstrftime.php)
- Furthermore it's notable that the `time()` returns current timestamp only in GMT

Comment: Special thanks to @Dunky13 for the given solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158501/how-to-convert-user-local-timestamp-to-gmt-timestamp