# Timestamp isn't persisted as UTC

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

i have a created field in datetime and a modified field in timestamp.
this is my code

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
if ($this->isNewRecord)
$this->created = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$this->modified = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
```

when i create a new record i see datetime and timestamp with same time in Los Angeles time but i expect timestamp field to be in UTC. 
i mean if datetime field is something like '.. 08:00:00' timestamp should be '16:00:00' because US time is (UTC -08:00) and [DOC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) says

> TIMESTAMP values are converted from the current time zone to UTC for
>   storage

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the downvote. ***Correct*** timezone handling is an issue that many struggle with, especially when a database server is brought into the equation. I understand that there's no clear question stated, but it doesn't take much extrapolation in this case to figure out what the OP is getting at.

Comment: maybe question is not clear because my english is bad.

Comment: a.v. you probably didn't make it clear enough, that your question is about MySQL's datatype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TIMESTAMP` fieds are in fact converted to UTC **for storage**. That means, it's stored this way, but when selected it will be converted to connection's timezone. You can do an experiment: change your timezone (see below) to something else, and do the select for that timestamp.

Here's [MySQL docs about handling timezones](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

---

added: some console output for illustration

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> -- Let s see what is the current timezone setting on this server
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | SYSTEM              |
+--------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- I don t know what SYSTEM is set to, so just to be safe I ll set it to my timezone
mysql> set time_zone = '+01:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | +01:00              |
+--------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- Let s create a table for or test    
mysql> create table testTimestamp (ts timestamp);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.28 sec)

mysql> -- Now to insert current time into the test table
mysql> insert into testTimestamp values (now());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> -- Let s see how it looks like
mysql> select * from testTimestamp;
+---------------------+
| ts                  |
+---------------------+
| 2012-02-13 00:12:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> -- Now let s change session timezone to Los Angeles time
mysql> set time_zone = '-08:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- And let s look at our timestamp once again
mysql> select * from testTimestamp;
+---------------------+
| ts                  |
+---------------------+
| 2012-02-12 15:12:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: but i mean at now "timestamp is converted to  connection's timezone for storage"!? i checked this value in database

Comment: how? automatically by MySQL. Use `SET time_zone = '-08:00';` or `SET time_zone = '+02:00';` or ahtever you fancy, and see the difference when you do `SELECT`s

Comment: i am confused. 1 more question. why timestamp and datetime field in my example code show same time?

Comment: thank u so much Mchl. i got it. i wrongly expected to see utc in timestamp field but mysql show me timestamp with current time zone

Comment: Probably because your MySQL's time_zone is by default set to UTC-8.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `gmdate()` instead of `date()`

`date()` returns the result **according to `date_default_timezone_set()`** while `gmdate()` does the same **according to GMT/UTC**.

Please take a look at [The standard way for switching from/to user_timezone and gmt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099473/the-standard-way-for-switching-from-to-user-timezone-and-gmt).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why but my answer was downvoted! I think that a.v's problem should be solved this way. In his case, using `date` is incorrect and he should use `gmdate`. I would appreciate any clarification about the vote. I believe the reason is more important than the result itself!

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I think you're victim of OP's unclear question. He was in fact asking about MySQL datatype, while your answer is about PHP. Bad luck for you. I'll review your answers in other questions, and see if I can give you a +1 somewhere to compensate for that ;)